# Трансляция объекта до и после поворота

Tags: opengl

Имею некий отрисовываемый квадрат, который задан следующими координатами и он рисуется по индексам

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};
GLuint indices[] = {
  0, 1, 2,
  0, 2, 3
};
```

Этот объект транслируется (перемещается) вдоль оси Х по вектору `vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)`. На каком-то моменте я произвожу с этим объектом операцию поворота на 90 градусов и он вместо того чтобы двигаться вдоль оси х начинает двигаться вдоль оси у.

Как найти новый вектор движения так, чтобы он снова производил движение вдоль оси х или как сделать так, чтобы поворот объекта не влиял на его направление.

Comment: Сразу возникает вопрос: А нельзя сначала подвинуть объект в нужную точку, а потом поворачивать?

Comment: Дилемма в том, что мне нужно постоянно так делать. Пишу змейку простую и у неё есть текстура головы. Мне эту голову нужно поворачиваться чтобы она боком не ходила)

Answer (score 0):

> Как найти новый вектор движения ...

Храните вектор "движения вперед" и поворачивайте его.

К примеру, начинаете вы с движения +X, поворачиваете на Pi/2, теперь вектор движения должен стать +Y `vec2(1.0f, 0.0f)` * Pi/2 --> `vec2(0.0f, 1.0f)`.

Если же вам не надо его менять - не меняйте его, пусть остается +X `vec2(1.0f, 0.0f)`.